# how to get the entity id from "create action controller" to the Textfield on the view after saving new entity

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

When I create a new entity in asp.net mvc - there is a call to **create** controller, and after:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

I'm using:

```
var newID = Client.Id;
```

How can I send back this **Id** to the view without full "post back" of the page?

The issue is my asp acting like "spa app" with jQuery to load contents to my splitter panes.

the js code:

```
 $('form').validate({
    rules: {
        .......
    },
    messages: {
        .......
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: form.method,
            url: form.action,
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                //if your return is just text then just convert to JSON
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                if (json.Success) {
                    $('#ClientIdTxt').val(data.Key);
                }
           }
         });
        form.preventDefault();
    }
 });
```

the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = ".......")] alfon alfon)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.alfon.Add(alfon);
                db.SaveChanges();

                Response.Write("{ \"Success\": true, \"Key\":  " + alfon.ClientNum + "    }");
                return null; 
            }
            return View(alfon);
        }
```

well: were am i go wrong ?
why i get a new page with the Json instead of get the Json "behind the seen" as parameter to >> $('#ClientIdTxt') as i need ?

Comment: show you action and view

Answer (score 0):

Perform a `POST` using jQuery AJAX, respond with a JSON message that will contain the ID and set it on the `success` event of the AJAX call.  Works great.

```
$("#yourFormName").submit(function(event){
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#yourFormName").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           //if your return is just text then just convert to JSON
           var json  = JSON.parse( data);
           if (json.Success ){
             $('#yourElementId').val(data.Key);
           }
       }
     });
  event.preventDefault();  //prevent the page from posting
});
```

In your controller:

```
Context.Response.Write("{ \"Success\": true, \"Key\":  " + yourObject.Id + " }");
return null;  //<-- return a null ActionResult
```

Comment: i'm using this function to edit in my cshtml:                                submitHandler: function (form) {
            
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#result').html("saved");
                }
            });
        }

Comment: then send your new key from the controller using json.  look at my example in the controller.

Comment: look at my answer, I updated it.  You need to prevent the `classic` post by calling `.preventDefault();`

Comment: change your `url` property in the ajax call to whatever controller/action you want.

Comment: i did add the preventDefault() and still the page post back to this link, and i see this >> { "Success": true, "Key": 7799 } : which is the write id but i don't want post back.

Comment: i don't understand, you are saying it's POSTing back twice or once?  It's suppose to post back once.

Comment: please upvote checkmark once you feel this has helped you, I appreciate the points.

Comment: i did change the url to : form.action. post once to this link:  localhost:1227/Alfon/Create

Comment: i don't want to change the whole page address. as i wrote i'm using "spa" application and after create i want to stay at the same view.

Comment: changing the controller doesn't have anything to do with changing the view.

Comment: you can change the POST url target, you are not even returning a view, you are returning JSON.  I don't think you understand how this really works.

Comment: I update My Code in this question where am i go wrong ???? how can i get the id parameter without navigate to the page with a json ?